# Requesting for Isolated scope / inherited scope in different order

Tags: angularjs

I have declared two directives on an element: one requesting for isolated scope and the other one requesting for inherited scope. Here how it looks:

**The Code**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('mainDir', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            title: '='
        },
        link: function(scope) {
            scope.title = "A";
        }
    }
});


app.directive('subMainDir', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: true,
        link: function (scope) {            
             scope.title = "A";          
        }
    }
});


app.controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.title = "Hi";
});
```

**The following line works fine:**

```
<div sub-main-dir main-dir title="title"></div>
```

**But the following line:**

```
<div main-dir title="title" sub-main-dir></div>
```

throwing error mentioning :

> angular1.2.0-rc.2.js:7861 Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple
>   directives [mainDir, subMainDir] asking for isolated scope on:

Why does the first line works but the second one throws an exception ?

Comment: Have you tried just updating to the latest stable angularjs version? 1.2.0.rc.2 is very old, dozens of bugs have been fixed since then, and rc.2 is not even a stable version.

Comment: Yes tried now and it fixed it. Thanks:)